# How can I redirect users to different website variant based on last used variant?

Tags: javascript, html, web, redirect, cookies

I have 2 variants of my website (say, A & B).
They're stored on the server at /a/ & /b/.

On my home page (/index.html), I wanna give users the option to choose (mostly a button) which variant to visit.

Then, I want to set that variant as the default for the user, so, the next time, the user tries to visit index.html, he/she will be redirected to the last visited variant.

Both the variants will have toggles to switch to the other one. So, if a user switches to the other one (say B from A), I'd like to set the new one (B) as the default so that the user gets redirected to the new one (B) next time he/she visits /index.html.

The redirects are supposed to work only on the /index.html page, so that if the users visit the variant specific webpage by directly typing the URL, they don't get redirected. However, the preferences should get changed, i.e., if last time the user had visited variant A and now, has used the URL of variant B, the next time he/she visits /index.html, he/she should be redirected to B.

I am making a wild guess by saying that cookies and JavaScript can help me achieve this.

Can someone tell me if and how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about JavaScript, but, I achieved it through PHP:

In the `/a/`, I created an index.php file. It contains the following code:

```
<?php
setcookie("chosen_variant","a",time()+86400*365,"/","domain.tld",1);
?>
<html>
...
</html>
```

The `setcookie()` function has the following parameters:

`"chosen_variant"` is the name of the cookie,
`"a"` is the value,
`time()+86400*365` means it's valid for 365 days,
`"/"` means it's valid for entire domain,
`"domain.tld"` means it's valid for all subdoamins of domain.tld,
`"1"` means it's transferred only on secured connections.

So, when `/a/index.php` is loaded in the browser for the first time, it sets a cookie with the name `chosen_variant` and the value as `a`, which expires in 365 days, is valid for my entire domain and all sub-domains and is transferred only on secured connections.

Then, I did the same in `/b/`.

Then, I created a index.php file in the root of my website with the following code:

```
<?php
if($_COOKIE['chosen_variant'] == "a")
 {header("Location: /a/index.php");}
elseif($_COOKIE['chosen_variant'] == "b")
 {header("Location: /b/index.php");}
else
 {}
?>
<html>
...
</html>
```